# SDL Tridion Sites 9 Cloud - Custom Pages Supported?

Tags: sdl-cloud

Are Custom Pages supported in the SDL Sites 9 Cloud?  I have an ASP.NET MVC Custom Page app that uses the Core Service that shows some reports / info to the end user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it's supported but can't be hosted on the same machine as the CM. You have the choice of running it on a fenced server in the SDL Cloud environment or running it outside of SDL cloud and connecting to the CoreService to generate your reports.

Comment: ^^ This. Because of SLAs on environments, SDL will not allow running custom pages on the same server, as the impact of that code on the server is unpredictable and outside of SDL's control.

Comment: For option 1, the fenced server, would we need to stand up a new CMS server in the SDL cloud?  For option 2, any docs on configuring the firewall / security for that?

Comment: A fenced server is just a standalone server hosted next to the CM that you can install your custom code on. It will have to interact with the CM over CoreService as well. For option 2 I think the standard approach is to use IP whitelisting.